# How to set font smoothing (WPF)?

Tags: fonts, wpf

In my WPF application often used small size text (12-13 px). As a result I see a bad display of it (imho, for me). ClearType used (but does not help).

Example (from above is a desired result):

[image]

How you thinks, what must be helpful for me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs to stack overflow

Comment: Funny, but there they told me to go here...

Comment: Then why you did not vote against?

Comment: I did that message is generated by the vote system. In anycase you question does not have any actionable points, what i think is not a question. Yes text antialiasing is sometimes an issue. Not much you can do about that.

Comment: Just to be clear: Above is the desired result and below is what you obtain, right? If so, note that the below case looks as if it has compression artifacts, which makes it quite difficult to make good statements about the actual font rendering. Also, what exactly do you consider bad?

Comment: display. letters ripple.

Comment: I'm voting to close as it's not clear what you're asking.  Do you want advice on how to make fonts look better in your software application, or an explanation about why anti-aliased text looks the way it does?

Comment: Explain how to do better.

Answer (score 1):

Use a bitmap font just in the wanted size. Get one that is designed for small size. Prevent any scaling and smoothing.

Comment: ok, what bitmap font you advices for me? With Segoe UI font style.

Comment: Forgot to add that Kaspersky Antivirus font is perfect! It is represented in the picture (which is on top).

Comment: I was told that subpixel (ClearType) smoothing is applied. Is this true?

Comment: @D.Stark  Unfortunately bitmap fonts cannot have very large stylistic variation spectrum. It's difficult enough to get all needed characters acceptably visible. Please, check, if something applicable exixts here http://www.dafont.com/bitmap.php?page=1&text=Bitmap+Text+for+Everyone. I'm not a programmer so I cannot give proper answers for that area. But surely any smoothing means harmful blurring too in small sizes.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom image looks like it is using greyscale subpixel rendering. This is normal behavior in WPF for certain circumstances. The following randomly selected [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9c6ebb19-fe6a-4930-bf26-e71c33062351/bug-cleartype-goes-to-grayscale-subpixel-rendering-incorrectly?forum=wpf) summarizes better than I can:

> This is not a bug actually, rather it's a known limitation, there are
>   some of situations in which font antialiasing algorithm will fallback
>   to grayscale, they are:
>
> 1. Text content rendered into software render target using RenderTargetBitmap.
> 2. Text content hosted inside layered windows (aka ContextMenus, ToolTips etc).
> 3. Text content rasterized into VisualBrush.
> 4. Text content rendered into a CompostionTarget whose Background property is set to Colors.Transparent to support areo glass frame
>      extension.

Note: this is definitely a stack overflow question.